# IN operator with Inner query SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-query

I have this query

```
SELECT *
FROM `posts`
WHERE `language` IN ( SELECT `possible_languages` FROM `users` WHERE user_id = ? );
```

In the table `posts`: languages can be either `en` or `ar`
In the table `users`: `possible_languages` can be either `'en'`, `'ar'` or `'en','ar'`
When the selected value is `'en','ar'` the query doesn't work
I want it to be able to select Posts that are either `en` or `ar` IN ('en','ar')

Comment: Sounds to me like a data issue, could you post examples of the data from both tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `in` with such lists.  You can do this with `exists`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM `posts` p
WHERE exists (select 1
              from `users` u
              where u.user_id = ? and find_in_set(p.language, u.possible_languages)
             )
```

This will be more efficient if you have an index on `users(user_id, possible_languages)`.

Comment: `AND FIND_IN_SET(language, ( SELECT possible_languages FROM users WHERE user_id = ?) )` that was the working query inspired by your solution. Thanks

Comment: If there is only one user record per user_id (i.e. user_id is the primary key).  I don't really think that an index on users(user_id,possible_languages) would make much difference.

Answer (score 1):

May be more efficient as a join

```
SELECT posts.*
FROM `posts`, `users`
WHERE find_in_set(`language`,`possible_languages`)
AND user_id = ?
```

A more efficient query for this however may be:

```
SELECT posts.*
  FROM posts,users
 WHERE (language=possible_languages OR possible_languages='ar,en')
   AND user_id=?
```

Assuming the values in language and possible_languages are only as you specified.  In this case an index on language in posts is useful.